# Expected value of difference between two dice rolls

Tags: probability

If two dice are rolled, what is the EV of the difference in both value?

I found the following solution, and have a question.

If the question is $E[X-Y]$, then it must equal $0$.  I assume the question is $E[|X-Y|]$.

Since it is symmetrical, we can assume $Y < 4$.  Half the time $X > 3$. Then $E[|X-Y|]=E[X-Y]=5-2=3$.

The other half, if just nine cases: $3$ they are the same; $2$ they are two apart, $(3,1)$ and $(1,3)$; and the remaining $4$ they are $1$ apart. So $$E[|X-Y|]= \frac{3 \cdot 0+2 \cdot 2+4 \cdot 1}{9} = \frac{8}{9}$$

$$E[|X-Y|] = .5 \cdot 3+.5 \cdot \frac{8}{9} = \frac{35}{18}$$

I'm confused in "The other half" case. In the first half, we were able to assume that the $E[X]-E[Y] = 5-2 = 3$, since $X$ ranges $\{4,5,6\}$ and $Y$ ranges $\{1,2,3\}$. For the second case, $X$ ranges $\{1,2,3\}$ and $Y$ ranges $\{1,2,3\}$.

Why is the $E[X-Y]$ not equal to $2-2 = 0$? What tells you **intuitively** that you need to break this one down in cases, while you can leave the first one with the obvious $5-2=3$? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain the logic behind the solution, and therefore propose a simpler one.
The absolute value of the difference can take 5 values: 0 (6 cases), 1 (10), 2 (8), 3 (6), 4 (4), 5 (2).
Correspondingly,  the expected value is:
$$
\frac {0\times 6+1\times 10+2\times 8+3\times 6+4\times 4+ 5\times 2}{36}=\frac {35}{18}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

As it is said, we are clearly looking for $\mathsf{E}[|X-Y|]$, and not $\mathsf{E}[X-Y]$ (which is $\mathsf{E}[X]-\mathsf{E}[Y]=0$, by linearity).

In the first case, $\mathsf{E}[|X-Y|]=\mathsf{E}[X-Y]$, because $X>Y$.

However, in the second case, $\mathsf{E}[|X-Y|]\neq\mathsf{E}[X-Y]$ and you need to figure the absolute value out. Equal once do cancel out to zero. However, the rest like $(3,1)$ and $(1,3)$ are both $2$. Not $2$ and $-2$.